# Marketing Cloud email sent < 24 hours not showing up in Discovery report

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I'm having an issue where I send and email and then several hours later I'll try to create a discovery report to show other stakeholder the clicks, bounces, etc. However, the send does not appear in the report until the next day.

Is this normal? Does a send only appear in Discover report after 24 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discover usually is populated once per day as its a seperate reporting platform. You can usually find a Automation that is scheduled to run once per day which transfers all the data for the previous 24 hours.

The non discover reports do run instantly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Andrew this is exactly the response I was looking for. Can you provide more insight on the “automation” that’s running? Where can I find it? Or is it on the backend?

Comment: the automation normally has your organisation name in it and in my instance contains alot of Data Factory Utility activities with all "extracts" listed.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_di_restart_paused_account.htm&type=5